# How to rename all the files (without for loop) in a single line command?

Tags: sed, gawk

I want to rename all the files in my home directory (example abc), in the format (abc_bkp) without using any loops and it should be a single line command in unix (bash script).

Comment: Take a look at Perl's standalone `rename` command.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `man find` could be a starting point for your search. Or just search `[sed] rename all files` on Stackoferflow

Comment: Why is this tagged `sed` and `gawk`?  Neither of those tools is appropriate for this.

Comment: Hi william the task can also be done using sed and awk as they are search and replace commands

Comment: akshay no it **cannot** be done with sed or awk. There is no "rename file" command in either tool. sed and awk are for manipulating text, a **shell** is for manipulating files and processes. I can't believe this question with no code, no sample input, and no expected output has collected answers!

Answer (score 1):

If the directory contains nothing but files, this should do it:

```
ls | xargs -I {} mv {} {}_bkp
```

If it contains subdirectories, links, and other things you don't want to rename, you must filter the output of `ls`. Here is a crude way to do it; maybe someone can suggest a more elegant approach:

```
ls -l | grep ^- | cut -d' ' -f 13 | xargs -I {} mv {} {}_bkp
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but as i am new to unix can you please me what this xargs and cut command that you have used.  This is what i am getting a error message when i execute  ls | xargs -I {} mv {} {}_bkp                               
 mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `_bkp' with directory `Desktop/'                                                                         
mv: cannot overwrite non-directory `_bkp' with directory `LearnC/' so what can be done now

Comment: @akshaysiddamal: I think RavinderSingh13's solution is more elegant than mine. My solution works when I test it, I don't know why it fails when you try it. I suggest you decide whether you want to rename directories, then try using this approach to rename a single file (e.g. `echo abc | xargs -I {} mv {} {}_bkp`) and see what happens. And try the commands one by one (first `ls`, then `ls -l`, then `ls -l | grep ^-`...) to see how they work. And study the man pages and online tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use loops then I believe the BEST way could be `find` command, try following command as a DRY run first and once you are satisfy with results then you could remove `echo` from it to give a real shot.

```
find -type f -or -type d | xargs -I %  echo mv % %_bkp
```

`-I`: From `man xargs` page:

> -I replace-str
>             Replace  occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not
>   terminate
>             input items; instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ravinder its perfect one its working fine but can you guide me what xargs -I is doing as i am new to unix

Comment: @akshaysiddamal, see my edit now and let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: if i want to rename all files and directory then this is what it has to be find . -type f | find . -type d| xargs -I %   mv % %_bkp or is there any command that does both directory and files rename at a shot

Comment: @akshaysiddamal, this is a LEARNING site, we all learn here, for questions first try to solve them by yourself from google/books etc once you are not able to solve them please put question here(with your efforts please). You could start a new thread after following my above mentioned advice please, thanks and cheers !!